# Java Generics won't compile

Tags: java, generics

```
public class GenMethodDemo{

        public GenMethodDemo(){
            Sum.<Integer,Integer,Integer>sum(1,2);       
        }

        public static void main(String args[]){
            new GenMethodDemo();
        }
    }

    class Sum{

     public static final <S extends Number,Z extends S,X extends S> S sum(Z v1,X v2){
            System.out.printf("v1=%1$s,v2=%2$s%n",v1.getClass(),v2.getClass());
            return v1+v2;
        }
```

Error get:

```
error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
        return v1+v2;
  first type:  Z
  second type: X
  where Z,S,X are type-variables:
    Z extends S declared in method <S,Z,X>sum(Z,X)
    S extends Number declared in method <S,Z,X>sum(Z,X)
    X extends S declared in method <S,Z,X>sum(Z,X)
1 error
```

Can't understand what i'm doing wrong? If i change S.Z.X with Integer - all works fine but why with generics code won't compile?

Refactored code to:

```
public class GenMethodDemo2{

    public GenMethodDemo2(){
        Sum.<Integer>sum(1,2);        
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new GenMethodDemo2();
    }
}
class Sum{

    public static final <S extends Integer> S sum(S v1,S v2){
        System.out.printf("v1=%1$s, v2=%2$s%n",v1.getClass(),v2.getClass());
        return v1+v2;
    }
} 

error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to S
        return v1+v2;
  where S is a type-variable:
    S extends Integer declared in method <S>sum(S,S)
1 error
```

So, S supposed to be an Integer or any subclass of Integer class, in any way it definitely should be possible to + their values. What's wrong with this version?

`S extends Integer` but `int cannot be converted to S`, how it could be? Why there is no autoboxing?

Comment: There is no `+` operator defined for `Number`, only specific subclasses of `Number`.

Comment: Even if Number change to Integer - it won't work but i'm define Integer as a type for method sum, so why it's not inlined as S,Z and V?

Comment: Integer + Integer only works because of automatic unboxing to int + int.

Comment: @user124 that's because the result of adding two `Integer`s is an `Integer`, not an `S`.

Comment: Also, note that `Z` and `X` are redundant, because they are used 1) non-generically (not like e.g. `List<Z>`), 2) only in method parameters. You may as well just use `S` in their place.

Comment: Refactored the code, update question. There is still not clear why it shows errors?

Comment: Look at the error message it's returning.  When your code was `<S extends Number>`, the error was `operator + is undefined`.  Now you have `<S extends Integer>`, the operator is fine, and the error now is `Cannot convert from int to S`.  This is because it can do the addition (which results in an int), but you've declared the Sum function to return an S.  For example, suppose you've called Sum with your own `class MyMegaInteger extends Integer`.  When Java does the addition and gets an int, it has no way of converting from that `int` to an instance of MyMegaInteger for it to return.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is because there is no `+` operator defined for `Number`, only specific subclasses of `Number`. For example, `+` is defined for `Integer`, `Double` etc, but not `BigInteger`, `BigDecimal` or any other non-standard implementation of `Number`.

There is no good way to do generic addition. You end up having to provide a `BinaryOperator<S>`, so your code looks like:

```
sum(1, 2, Integer::sum);
sum(1.0, 2.0, Double::sum);
```

which is more verbose than just:

```
1 + 2
1.0 + 2.0
```

---

The compiler requires `+` to be defined for the *compile-time* types of `v1` and `v2`. It doesn't matter if they are `Integer` (or whatever) at runtime: the decision as to whether to allow the `+` is made by the compiler, because it has to be able to guarantee that the method is type-safe for any arguments.

The method above is compiled to this:

```
 public static final Number sum(Number v1, Number v2){
   System.out.printf("v1=%1$s,v2=%2$s%n",v1.getClass(),v2.getClass());
   return v1+v2;
 }
```

This is called [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

If `+` isn't defined for a `Number`, this code isn't allowed.

Comment: So,  <code>System.out.printf("v1=%1$s,v2=%2$s%n",v1.getClass(),v2.getClass());</code> shows that there are v1-> Integer and v2-> Integer

Comment: It doesn't matter how you call the method. Java's not like C++ where each instantiated template is compiled independently. The method needs to be compilable generically for all possible `S`, `Z`, and `X`.

Comment: Please [read previous comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56419689/java-generics-wont-compile/56419712?noredirect=1#comment99434891_56419689).

Comment: @user124 [Seriously, man, read the comments people address directly to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56419689/java-generics-wont-compile/56419712?noredirect=1#comment99435044_56419748).

Comment: I mean a new, code listing, not one line. Sorry, but ctlrL+K don't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

As a general solution for all inbuilt `Number` extensions:

```
public static Number sum(final Number a, final Number b) {
    return new BigDecimal(a.toString()).add(new BigDecimal(b.toString()));
}
```

(Note: there's no guarantee that `toString()` will give a `String` which is parseable by `BigDecimal` but it does for all the inbuilt JDK `Number` extensions to the best of my knowledge.)

If you wanted to do something more clever, you could do some checks with `instanceof` to find the types of the inputs and work from there, but I tried that once for implementing `Comparable` between all `Number`s and the performance wasn't any better than casting to `BigDecimal`.

Comment: I wan't to realize what i did wrong with generics, thank you, but i could resolve this without generics.

Comment: Even if i return `Integer.valueOf(1)` - > code do not compiling. So, the question is: if S,Z and X changed to `Integer`, because `v1.getClass()` and `v2.getClass()` -> prints as Integer, why it didn't works even if i manually return `Integer`?

Comment: @user124 you can't return an `Integer` from a method where you've said it returns `S`, where `S extends Number`. `S` *might* be `Integer`, but it could be anything else.